# Generate a unique integer based on given string

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

There are many answers already on the subject, but I can't find any that looks like what I'm looking for.

I would need to generate a unique negative ID (int) from a given string. Would be happy if there was the decoding as well, but not mandatory.

Comment: Unique in what context? Universally, per network, per computer, per session, per user, per process, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `myString.GetHashCode()` it's not guaranteed to be unique, but will definetely return the same key for the same string.

Comment: And if it isn't already negative, he'd need to negate it. That's going to double the number of collisions of course.

Comment: "The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, there is no such conversion. `int` size is limited by 32 bits, while `string` size is pretty much unlimited. You will get collisions unless you apply some restrictions to your strings.

Comment: Good remark. I am using the answer proposed below but will pay attention to my string length. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to generate a unique int for an **arbitrary length** string.

int has 32 bits of data, a string of 100 characters (assuming C#) will have 1600 bits of data, so you will have at least 1600/32 collisions.

[being funny]

you could :

```
string a = "dgfadg";
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(a);
BigInteger integer=  new BigInteger(bytes);
```

[/being funny]